# Both INSERT and UPDATE in one query

Tags: php, mysql

trying to make a form that both updates the data in one table, and inserts data into another table. I'm very new to php so I just tried writing one query that updates the first table and then another one to insert into the other one but when I do it like this only one of the queries are executed.

This is my code:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form2")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO utlaan (Skolebok_idSkolebok, elev_email, utlaansdato,                
innlevert) VALUES (%s, %s, NOW(), 0)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Skolebok_idSkolebok'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['elev_email'], "text"),
$insertSQL =sprintf("UPDATE skolebok, utlaan SET                   
utlant = 1 WHERE skolebok.idSkolebok=utlaan.Skolebok_idSkolebok"));



mysql_select_db($database_Bibliotekkobling, $Bibliotekkobling);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $Bibliotekkobling) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Any help apritiated

Comment: Why not perform it in a transaction?

Comment: You're only running the UPDATE query - you're overwriting the contents when you set it. The simplest way to do this is to call `mysql_query` twice, once with each query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the contents of `$insertSQL`. You need to first call `mysql_query` on the insert query, and then on update query. Like this:

```
mysql_select_db($database_Bibliotekkobling, $Bibliotekkobling);

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO utlaan (Skolebok_idSkolebok, elev_email, utlaansdato,                
innlevert) VALUES (%s, %s, NOW(), 0)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Skolebok_idSkolebok'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['elev_email'], "text"));

// First call the insert query
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $Bibliotekkobling) or die(mysql_error());

$updateSQL =sprintf("UPDATE skolebok, utlaan SET                   
utlant = 1 WHERE skolebok.idSkolebok=utlaan.Skolebok_idSkolebok");

// Now call the update query
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $Bibliotekkobling) or die(mysql_error());
```